# Solr Query Log - Need SQL Results

Tags: solr

We are usig solr 1.4.1 Dataimport handler to build our solr index. Whenver a record on table( where the DIH queries) is updated we call the DIH with a query that updates that solr record with the new values. Right now the problem is sometimes the solr records are not updated eventhough we see on the logs that solr query have been called when there is  record update on the DB side. Is there anyway we can turn on solr to show us  the follwing stuff onthe logs;

1. Show the SQL query it's executing
2. Results returned ( Both the count as well as the individual records).

Tried debugQuery=true but that does not give us the No.2(above) we are looking for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks
s

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see the sql queries fired by Solr data import handler if you change your logging level to fine or finest. 
You can dynamically change the logging level for solr.

You can also use http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Commands, the debug feature to sample test you data.

debugQuery would only help you debug search results and relevance.

Comment: we did turn on the logging to the finest and able to see the sql queries but not the results.We want to see what happens after it?. Does the query returns any rows or not?... Is there any way solr can return the sql execution result rows to the logs?...

Comment: If you want detailed data - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Interactive_Development_Mode  Choose the 'verbose' option to get detailed information about the intermediete steps. What was emitted by the query and what went into the Transformer and what was the output.  However, this is not outputed to the logs and can be used only for debugging.  Might help you